# How to remove Keystonejs 5 github repo url from the admin ui?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, keystonejs

How I can remove this Git Repo URL from the Keystone.js Admin Panel ?
[Keystone JS website](https://www.keystonejs.com/)

[image: The Admin UI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's displayed only in dev mode.

- set `ENABLE_DEV_FEATURES` to `false`
- or modify the file `node_modules/@keystonejs/app-admin-ui/client/components/Nav.js`